# Spring MockMvc async test does not rollback

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to convert Spring REST Controller into async mode, but I have problems running tests using `MockMvc`. The test passes, but it does not rollback DB changes, so I end up with test data in DB. When using synchronous controller, data gets rolled back correctly.

This is my controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
public Callable<ResponseEntity<Void>> userSignup(@RequestBody User user, HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request) {
    return () -> {
        String id = userService.createUser(user);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setLocation(new URI(findServerUrlFromRequest(request, "/users/id/" + id)));
        return new ResponseEntity<>(headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    };

}
```

And this is the test:

```
 @Test
@Rollback(true)
public void createUserTest() throws Exception{
    User user = new User();
    user.setFirstname("John");
    user.setLastname("Doe");
    user.setEmail("user@mail.com");
    user.setPassword("password");
    JAXBContext ctx = JAXBContext.newInstance(User.class);
    Marshaller marshaller = ctx.createMarshaller();
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    marshaller.marshal(user, writer);
    writer.close();
    System.out.println("XML: " + writer.toString());

    MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(post("/users").content(writer.toString()).contentType("application/xml")).andExpect(request().asyncStarted()).andReturn();
    mockMvc.perform(asyncDispatch(result)).andExpect(status().isCreated()).andExpect(header().string("Location",org.hamcrest.Matchers.startsWith("http://localhost:80/users/id"))).andDo(print()).andReturn();

}
```

I'm thinking it's some kind of configuration issue, but can't figure out what is the problem. Can anybody give me a hint?

Comment: Did you find the reason?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JUnit rollback transaction with @Async method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39042930/junit-rollback-transaction-with-async-method)