# JUnit rollback transaction with @Async method

Tags: java, junit, spring-transactions, spring-test, spring-async

I am writing an integration test using `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`.
I have a base class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration({ /*my XML files here*/}) 
@Ignore
public class BaseIntegrationWebappTestRunner {

@Autowired
protected WebApplicationContext wac; 

@Autowired
protected MockServletContext servletContext; 

@Autowired
protected MockHttpSession session;

@Autowired
protected MockHttpServletRequest request;

@Autowired
protected MockHttpServletResponse response;

@Autowired
protected ServletWebRequest webRequest;

@Autowired
private ResponseTypeFilter responseTypeFilter;

protected MockMvc mockMvc;

@BeforeClass
public static void setUpBeforeClass() {

}

@AfterClass
public static void tearDownAfterClass() {

}

@Before
public void setUp() {
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).addFilter(responseTypeFilter).build();
}

@After
public void tearDown() {
    this.mockMvc = null;
}
}
```

Then I extend it and create a test using mockMvc:

```
public class MyTestIT extends BaseMCTIntegrationWebappTestRunner {

@Test
@Transactional("jpaTransactionManager")
public void test() throws Exception {
    MvcResult result = mockMvc
            .perform(
                    post("/myUrl")
                            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                            .characterEncoding("UTF-8")
                            .content("content")
                            .headers(getHeaders())
            ).andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML))
            .andExpect(content().encoding("ISO-8859-1"))
            .andExpect(xpath("/*[local-name() ='myXPath']/")
                    .string("result"))
            .andReturn();
}
```

In the end of the flow, an entity is saved into DB. But the requirement here is that is should be done asynchronously. So consider this method is called:

```
@Component
public class AsyncWriter {

    @Autowired
    private HistoryWriter historyWriter;

    @Async
    public void saveHistoryAsync(final Context context) {
        History history = historyWriter.saveHistory(context);
    }
}
```

Then `HistoryWriter` is called:

```
@Component
public class HistoryWriter {

    @Autowired
    private HistoryRepository historyRepository;

    @Transactional("jpaTransactionManager")
    public History saveHistory(final Context context) {
        History history = null;
        if (context != null) {
            try {
                history = historyRepository.saveAndFlush(getHistoryFromContext(context));
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                LOGGER.error(String.format("Cannot save history for context: [%s] ", context), e);
            }
        }
        return history;
    }
}
```

The problem with all this is that after test is done, `History` object is left in the DB. I need to make test transaction to rollback all changes in the end.

Now, what I've tried so far:

1. Remove `@Async` annotation. Obviously, this cannot be the solution, but was done to confirm rollback will be perform without it. Indeed, it is.
2. Move `@Async` annotation to `HistoryWriter.saveHistory()` method to have it in one place with `@Transactional`. This article https://dzone.com/articles/spring-async-and-transaction suggests it should work this way, but for me, no rollback is done after test.
3. Swap places of these two annotations. It does not give the desired result as well.

**Does anyone have any idea how to force rollback of the DB changes made in asynchronous method?**

Side notes:

Transaction configuration:

`<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true" transaction- manager="jpaTransactionManager"/>`

Async configuration:

`<task:executor id="executorWithPoolSizeRange" pool-size="50-75" queue-capacity="1000" />
<task:annotation-driven executor="executorWithPoolSizeRange" scheduler="taskScheduler"/>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does anyone have any idea how to force rollback of the DB changes made in asynchronous method?

That is unfortunately not possible.

Spring manages transaction state via `ThreadLocal` variables. A transaction started in another thread (e.g., the one created for your `@Async` method invocation) can therefore *not* participate in a transaction managed for the parent thread.

This means that the transaction used by your `@Async` method is **never** the same as the [test-managed transaction](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#testcontext-tx-test-managed-transactions) which gets automatically rolled back by the Spring TestContext Framework.

Thus, the only possible solution to your problem is to *manually* undo the changes to the database. You can do this using `JdbcTestUtils` to execute an SQL script programmatically within an `@AfterTransaction` method, or you can alternatively configure an SQL script to be executed declaratively via Spring's `@Sql` annotation (using the *after* execution phase). For the latter, see [How to execute @Sql before a @Before method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27126974/sql-execute-before-than-before/27156080#27156080) for details.

Regards,

Sam (*author of the Spring TestContext Framework*)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. Since I could not archive this, and now I know its not possible, I ended up creating separate spring config xml for testing, in which removed `<task:annotation-driven executor="executorWithPoolSizeRange" scheduler="taskScheduler"/>` so @Async won't work during testing and thus transaction will be rollbacked.

Comment: I have one more challenge now, could you please have a look?So I needed to add PowerMock to my test cases in addition to SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.
In order to do so I added
`@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)`
And now I would also like to utilize Parameterized runner. I checked https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-5292 and it seems I can use Spring Rules to make it work with Parameterized. But will it work with PowerMock as well? I tried to simply PowerMock delegate to Parameterized and add Spring rules, but didn't work. Can it be done?

Comment: I have never tried that combination, so I don't know whether it works or not.